# Issue with implementing Polyfill

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm getting error on IE8 : Object doesn't support this property or method

However it's working fine with Chrome or Mozilla

Code:

```
{
var optgroup_ids = optgroupids.split('%')[0].replace('_span', '');
 var optgroup_id = optgroup_ids.substr(0, optgroup_ids.lastIndexOf(optgroup_ids,'_'));
 error = true;
 mprint("Error in optgroup condition for optgroup id: " + optgroup_id + ": " + e.message, "red");
    }
```

I tried adding the below code snippet at top of Script as polyfill

```
if (!('lastIndexOf' in Array.prototype)) {

        Array.prototype.lastIndexOf= function(find, i /*opt*/) {
        if (i===undefined) i= this.length-1;
        if (i<0) i+= this.length;
        if (i>this.length-1) i= this.length-1;
        for (i++; i-->0;) /* i++ because from-argument is sadly inclusive */
            if (i in this && this[i]===find)
                return i;
        return -1;
    };
}
```

No Luck! Need help on how to add polyfills.

Comment: Which method ..? What is `mprint`? What is `_`?

Comment: See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf). It has an pollyfil example.

Comment: @Teemu Those are internal methods, we can ignore. I just need help in polyfill implementation.

Comment: @MrShumar No luck. Tried it

Comment: Now after your edit, this is getting even more weird. [`String.prototype.lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) has been supported by IE since version 6.

Comment: Can you post the optgroupids value? I try to create a sample using string data, it seems that the lastIndexOf method works well on my IE 8+. Please re-check the error message, are you sure the issue is related to the lastindexof method?